# Rounding alternate edges in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, rounding

I did saw other solutions where they use up and down images.
Which I found very complex for making alternate rounded edges.

Like this one below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I defined a smoothbutton which I used as Button in all my components:

```
<SmoothButton@Button>:
    background_color:(0,0,0,0)
    background_normal:''
    back_color: (0.565, 0.557, 0.698,0.8)
    border_radius:[0,35,0,35]
    font_name:'Comic'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:self.back_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size:self.size
            pos:self.pos
            radius:self.border_radius
```

Note the only catch here is :

```
border_radius:[0,35,0,35]
```